# react native app pausing on white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-router-flux

I have been working on an app for the past couple days and everything has been working fine. However, today I was adjusting the positions of some buttons and going to extremes in terms of their margins in order to test some things. I stopped messing with them and just added a couple screens and randomly the emulator (iPhone 6) paused at a white screen. Please help as I have not been able to find any useful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do when my react-native app is starting to bug out.

- Stop Packager and Clear [watchman cache](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968#issue-123828214)
- Uninstall the test app from the simulator
- Restart Packager

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. I reverted some commits and found the solution. Thank you.